# One column from one datetime format to anther

Tags: python

I feel annoying to change datetime format.

```
y_hat.head()

    0       year
0   649.003 1960-12-31
1   649.003 1961-12-31
2   649.003 1962-12-31
3   649.003 1963-12-31
4   649.003 1964-12-31
```

I have one column called['year'], I want to change it from '1960-12-31' to '1960'.
I have tried many methods, such as [Change datetime format from one to another programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32444120/change-datetime-format-from-one-to-another-programmatically)
Can someone provide a method for me and others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert column [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) and extract [`year`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.year.html):

```
df['year'] = pd.to_datetime(df['year']).dt.year
```

Or [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and extract first value of lists, then convert to integers:

```
df['year'] = df['year'].str.split('-').str[0].astype(int)
```

---

```
print (df)
         0  year
0  649.003  1960
1  649.003  1961
2  649.003  1962
3  649.003  1963
4  649.003  1964
```